# SOAP API Integration in Laravel 8 with soap client library

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, laravel-8, soap-client

I am trying to implement PAN API in SOAP in laravel 8 but getting error of : Invalid client id or secret.
This error is when we are using SOAP client library.

**NOTE:** I have configured same project in SOAP UI tool, it is giving correct response there.

Steps I have followed are as below:

1. Generated the request XML as suggested in the Ref document and saved in document. Sample Payload is below:

   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="url"
   xmlns:dit="url"
   xmlns:req="url">
   soapenv:Header/
   soapenv:Body
   dit:verifyDetails
   <dit:DitRequest uniqueRequestId="UniqueID">
   req:serviceIdID</req:serviceId>
   req:searchParams







   </req:searchParams>
   </dit:DitRequest>
   </dit:verifyDetails>
   </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
2. Used SOAP client library to encrypt and add signature in above payload

Below is the code we are sing for SOAP client:

```
        try{
            $newDate = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($request->cb_dob));
            $wsdl = "<Path to WSDL file>";
            $local_cert = "<path to public key in .cer format>";
            $private_cert = "<path to private key in .pem format>";
            $api_url = '<end points URL>';

            $context = stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                            'header' => 'clientid: <client ID>',
                            'header' => 'client-secret: <client Secret>'
                            )
            ));
            $option = array(
                              'location' => "< end point URL path>",
                              'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_2,
                              'connection_timeout'=>30000,
                              'ssl_method' => SOAP_SSL_METHOD_TLS,
                              'trace'=>1,
                              'exceptions'=>1,
                              'login'=>'<login>',
                              'password'=>'<pass>',
                              'stream_context' => $context,
                              'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
                              );
           
            $soapClient = new \SoapClient($wsdl, $option);
            
            $options = [
                'key' => 'AES256_CBC',
                'cert' => '<path to public key in .cer format>',
                'passphrase' => '<password>',
            ];

            // Convert options to SoapVar and SoapParam
            $key = new \SoapVar($options['key'], XSD_STRING);
            $cert = new \SoapVar($options['cert'], XSD_STRING);
            $passphrase = new \SoapVar($options['passphrase'], XSD_STRING);
            $authentication  = array(
                'client-secret' => '<client secret>',
                'clientid' => '<client ID>',
            );
            
            // Set encryption options as SoapParam
            $soapClient->__setSoapHeaders([
                new \SoapHeader($wsdl, 'key', $key, false),
                new \SoapHeader($wsdl, 'cert', $cert, false),
                new \SoapHeader($wsdl, 'passphrase', $passphrase, false),
                new \SoapHeader($wsdl, 'UserIdentifierSoapHeaderIn', $authentication, false),
            ]);
            
            
            $params = array('verifyResponse'=>array(
                                                      'uniqueRequestId'=> <unique ID>,                      
                                                      'serviceId' =><service ID>,
                                                      'searchParams'=>array(
                                                                             
                                        'searchParam'[0]=>array(
                                                                                         
                                        'searchKey'=>'pan',
                                                                                         
                                        'searchValue'=>$request->cb_pan
                                                                                      ),
                                                                             
                                        'searchParam'[1]=>array(
                                                                                         
                                        'searchKey'=>'fullName',
                                                                                         
                                        'searchValue'=>$request->cb_fullname
                                                                                      ),
                                                                             
                                       'searchParam'[2]=>array(
                                                                                         
                                            'searchKey'=>'dob',
                                                                                         
                                             'searchValue'=>$newDate
                                                                                      )      
                                                                            )
                                                      ) 
            
            );
            
            $theResponse1 = $soapClient->__soapCall('verify',$params); // verify functional calling in WSDL file                                       
                                                                                      
                                            
      } catch (SoapFault $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        var_dump(
                $soap_client->__getLastRequestHeaders(),
                $soap_client->__getLastRequest(),
                $soap_client->__getLastResponseHeaders(),
                $soap_client->__getLastResponse()
                );
      }
```

3. After sending signed XML data over the endpoint API getting an error.

> SoapFault
> Invalid client id or secret.